# Python - detect asterisk (*) during function call

Tags: python, slice, magic-methods

I need to detect that function is called with asterisk (*) when unpacking

**Problem**:

I have a special class that registers `__getitem__` keys.

these slicings will pass the obvious keys to `__getitem__`:

```
object[0], object[1,1], object['depth1']['depth2']
```

these is less obvious:

```
some_iterable = [97,4,56]
some_function(*some_iterable)
```

as it will pass not really the keys, but indexes: 0,1,2 (as it internally knows the list length)

---

**The issue** comes, when I create my own **not** subclassed class

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,key=None):
        self.registered_key = key

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return MyClass(key=key)
```

What happens is that when I call some function like this:

```
some_function(*MyClass())
```

it will create infinite loop because python somehow doesnt know how long is MyClass's unexistent iterable and therefore it will loop forever incrementing key from 0 to infinite....

**I think there is no solution to this problem, however it can be solved if I can detect usage of Asterisk(*) and resolve the problem with some inner logic. I couldnt find anywhere, how to detect it. Is there some way?**

**REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**: (Careful, infinite loop increasing memory[thats by the way also strange, that python doesnt protect you with recursion max-depth]):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, key=None):
        self.registered_key = key

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print(key)
        return MyClass(key=key)


def some_function(*args):
    pass


fake_iterable = MyClass()
some_function(*fake_iterable)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a strange quirk of unpacking I hadn't noticed before.

Now that I dug into the details of CPython to see what's up:

1. A `foo(*bar)` call gets turned into an `CALL_FUNCTION_EX` opcode.
2. These are handled [here in ceval.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5bf8bf2267cd109970b2d946d43b2e9f71379ba2/Python/ceval.c#L4327), where `Py_SETREF(callargs, PySequence_Tuple(callargs));` is done to get a tuple of call arguments.
3. [`PySequence_Tuple` in `abstract.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f0a6fde8827d5d4f7a1c741ab1a8b206b66ffd57/Objects/abstract.c#L1966) does some checks and calls `PyObject_GetIter(v);` to get an iterator of the object to use to create a tuple.
4. [`PyObject_GetIter`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f0a6fde8827d5d4f7a1c741ab1a8b206b66ffd57/Objects/abstract.c#L2716) does a check for `if (PySequence_Check(o)) return PySeqIter_New(o);`.
5. [`PySequence_Check`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f0a6fde8827d5d4f7a1c741ab1a8b206b66ffd57/Objects/abstract.c#L1642) looks at whether `Py_TYPE(s)->tp_as_sequence && Py_TYPE(s)->tp_as_sequence->sq_item != NULL` ...
6. and from [typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f0a6fde8827d5d4f7a1c741ab1a8b206b66ffd57/Objects/typeobject.c#L7424-L7425) we can see that `sq_item` corresponds to `__getitem__`.
7. `PySeqIter_New()` returns a sequence iterator, which is an iterator that apparently calls `__getitem__` until `StopIteration` gets raised.

As an aside,

> thats by the way also strange, that python doesnt protect you with recursion max-depth

it's because there's no recursion here. The new `MyClass`es you instantiate are dutifully packed onto the (future) args array of the `some_function` call, not used for anything.

---

Either way, you could circumvent this by declaring `__iter__` on the class. It seems unpacking will prefer attempting to iterate over the object.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,key=None):
        self.registered_key = key

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        # ...

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([0])
```